# Passing user object from one model to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Using Rails 3.2 and Paperclip to save photo. I am trying to save the user's Id to `user_id` in the `photos` table, counter cache increment in `photos_count` of `users` table. The `photos` are uploaded in another `shops`. Photos get uploaded, but I can't pass the `user` object to the `photo` model to do its miracle.

Things not working:

1. User Id fails to be saved in `photos` table `user_id` column
2. `photos_count` in `users` table doesn't get incremented whenever a photo is uploaded via `shops` form.

Below is my code:

```
# photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
  attr_accessible :data, :attachable_id, :attachable_type, :user_id
end

# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_protected :reviews_count, :rating_average, :photos_count
  has_many :photos, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :allow_destroy => true
end

# photos_controller.rb
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
end

# shops_controller.rb
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user, :only => [:new, :edit, :update, :create]

  def new
    @shop = Shop.new
  end

  def edit
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    if @shop.update_attributes(params[:shop])
      flash[:notice] = 'Successfully updated.'
      redirect_to shop_path(@shop)
    else
      render :action => :edit
    end
  end

  def create
    @shop = Shop.new(params[:shop])
    if @shop.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Successfully saved.'
      redirect_to shop_path(@shop)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
end

# shops/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @shop, :url => { :action => action, :type => type }, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.file_field :shop_photos_data, :multiple => true, :name => "shop[photos_attributes][][data]" %>
<% end %>
```

I tried to put this in the `photo.rb` but it returns `user` is nil:

```
  after_create :save_associated_user

  private

  def save_associated_user
    self.user_id = self.user
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attr_accessible user_id, not user.

Comment: And where in your code exactly are you setting user_id for the photo? Do you expect it to just *magicly* get set from nowhere?

Comment: Please see updated question. I did add an `after_create` in the `photo` model.

Comment: And where do you set photo.user? Your after_create hook is basically a no-operation. If self.user is anything then self.user_id will be set automatically by rails.

Answer (score 0):

In the form you have to set user_id in photos_attributes, something like this,

```
<%= form_for @shop, :url => { :action => action, :type => type }, :html => { :mult ipart  => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.file_field :shop_photos_data, :multiple => true, :name => "shop[photos_attributes][][data]" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :shop_photos_user_id, :value => current_user.id, :multiple => true, :name => "shop[photos_attributes][][user_id]" %>
<% end %>
```

After submitting you need to call some callbacks to update photos_count in users table

Comment: Only the last `user_id` get saved, the rest not saved.